# How to increase the limit of open connections on mac

Tags: load-testing, ulimit, k6, macbookpro

I need to trigger 30K+ requests from MacBook. How can I increase the limit to trigger that much of requests without any interruption?  is there any way to way to increase the limits? if 30k is not possible, is there any way to trigger 10k+ requests without any hindrance? I'm using the k6 tool to trigger requests.

I tried ulimit -n 1000000 but it didn't work. after reaching 5.5k+ requests. it starts throwing the EOF error.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following parameters:

```
sysctl kern.maxfiles
```

and

```
sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc
```

to see if the values are above 30k

Also it might be the case the number of open handles is not something which prevents you from running the test, 30k requests per second might be too much for a single machine so it's better to consider switching to a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) which can be launched in [clustered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) mode like [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Locust](https://locust.io/) or [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

Comment: I verified those parameters. it is more than 30k and I didn't try to trigger 30k+ requests per second. it will be 30k+ request for 20 mins+.  I tried to trigger a WebSocket connection and let it open for a while. I am doing a load test to check how many socket connections the server can withstand. scenario: triggering 30K requests within 20 mins and letting it open for 40 mins straight. could you please share any solution to resolve this issue?